# Execute function defined in Iframe in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have defined one function in html file. The html file is being used in iframe. So I want to call that function from parent page of Iframe. I have tried a lot but it is throwing system error.

http://jsfiddle.net/Y2fgv/2/

**parent file**

```
<iframe id="test1" name="test" src="http://jsfiddle.net/Y2fgv/1/embedded/result/" allowtransparency=true frameborder="0" ></iframe>

var f= frames['test']
f.a(5)
```

**Iframe file code**

```
function a(a){
alert(a)
}
```

Comment: `http://jsfiddle.net/Y2fgv/1/embedded/result/` does not define function `a()` in its page source.

Comment: That is the problem which I want to discussed about it

Comment: I found that it is working fine with event. but it is not working with when you execute function on page load

Comment: fixed: it is working with window.onload event

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
var f = document.getElementById("test1").contentWindow;
f.a(5); // to execute the function
```

Comment: Not working tried. contentWindow returning the same object as frames['test']